# Spring FilterSecurityInterceptor filter url by host

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement spring security in my web application.
The problem is that my web can work in two environments, b2b and b2c.

The b2b environment needs to have spring security control by username and password and b2c only in a few pages.

For example:

```
  www.myb2b.com/home  -> login required
  www.myb2c.com/home  -> no login required
  www.myb2c.com/private/admin  -> login required
```

The most important filter is the first and the second, the third one it can be achieved by other system.

How can I do this?

I'm trying to configure a custom FilterSecurityInterceptor to override doFilter funtion. But I'm having errors  for confilcts.

My appContext-web-security.xml (not completely because is still under development):

```
<beans:beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <custom-filter position="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="filterSecurityInterceptor" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="com.hotelbeds.tuiuk.web.spring.CustomSecurityInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="observeOncePerRequest" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin"
                    password="8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918"
                    authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="user"
                    password="04f8996da763b7a969b1028ee3007569eaf3a635486ddab211d512c85b9df8fb"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirements clear, it's quite easy to implement without any code level customization:

```
<bean id="b2bHostMatcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.ELRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg value="hasHeader('host','myb2b.com')"/>
</bean>

<bean id="b2cHostMatcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.ELRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg value="hasHeader('host','myb2c.com')"/>
</bean>

<security:http request-matcher-ref="b2bHostMatcher" ...>
    <!-- config for b2b requests -->
</security:http>


<security:http request-matcher-ref="b2cHostMatcher" ...>
    <!-- config for b2c requests -->
</security:http>
```

Note, that your IDE might complain about the two `<http>` elements neither of them having a `pattern` attribute, but you can safely ignore that, as it would only be a problem if both of them used the default `AntPathRequestMatcher`.